# Using optim in R [Restrict parameters to distinct natural numbers]

Tags: r, optimization, mathematical-optimization

I am trying to explore optim in R to solve a scenario but I am unable to restrict the function to work as desired. I read the help pages but could not make much progress since I am new to this area.

Let me explain to you about the problem in a smaller frame.
I have a dataframe which contains scores of students

```
scoreDf <- data.frame(Name = c("A", "B", "C"), Score = c(10, 15, 25))
```

**Objective**:
To select students (or groups of students) and order them in a sequence such that we minimise the sum-product of their scores and their position in the sequence as explain below:

> Minimize SUM (score * position); 
>   Subject to : Sum of Scores >= 30,
>   position = 0:n (distinct whole numbers in a sequence, 0 can be repeated) And return the
>   vector of positions

For example:

> In the given data, the desired solution is the sequence 2,0,1 for
>   A,B,C This means only A and C are considered since their sum of scores
>   = 10+25 = 35 >= 30 And value of objective function is 10*2 + 25*1 = 45 which is the minimum value. I am interested to know this result that
>   CA is that group in that order.

I tried to use optim but I could make much progress.
Please help.
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

`optim` is for continuous optimization but this problem is integer programming.

**1) lpSolve** Let X[i,j] = 1 if student j is in position i and zero otherwise.  Then use `lp` from the lpSolve package optimizing over the 9 elements of X.  Constrain X so that the sum of each row and the sum of each column of X can be no more than 1 and the sum of the scores is >= 30.   The objective coefficients are the positions times scores. Specify that the X variables are all binary, i.e. 0/1.

```
library(lpSolve)
scoreDf <- data.frame(Name = c("A", "B", "C"), Score = c(10, 15, 25)) 
n <- nrow(scoreDf)

obj <- c(outer(1:n, scoreDf$Score)) # obj fun coef of X[i,j] is position[i] * score[j]
cons <- rbind( outer(1:n, c(col(diag(n))), "==") + 0,  # lhs of col sum constraints on X
               outer(1:n, c(row(diag(n))), "==") + 0,  # lhs of row sum constraints on X
               rep(scoreDf$Score, each = n)) # lhs of sum of scores constraint on X
# col and row sums <= 1; sum of scores >= 30
dir <- c(rep("<=", 2 * n), ">=")
rhs <- c(rep(1, 2 * n), 30)  
ans <- lp("min", obj, cons, dir, rhs, all.bin = TRUE)

ans$objval
## [1] 45

# reshape ans$solution vector into a 0/1 matrix whose rows are positions and cols are names
X <- matrix(ans$solution, n, n, dimnames = list(pos = 1:n, Name = scoreDf$Name))
X
##    Name
## pos A B C
##   1 0 0 1
##   2 1 0 0
##   3 0 0 0

1:n %*% X # solution sequence
##     Name
##      A B C
## [1,] 2 0 1

# rework X into a data frame showing the Name for each pos
s <- subset(as.data.frame.table(X), Freq == 1, select = -Freq)
s[order(s$pos), ]
##   pos Name
## 7   1    C
## 2   2    A
```

**2) combinat** Another approach is to do a brute force search over all permutations and pick out the one with the minimum objective.  This may take excessive time and memory for large inputs but for small inputs it seems practical and it may be useful to have an independent alternative for cross checking.  We use `permn` from the combinat package to generate the permutations.  For each permutation find the minimum number of leading names whose scores sum to more than 29 (`no`) and then calculate the objective for just those (giving 0 to the rest) yielding `DF`. Each row of `DF` lists a permutation, `no` and the objective value `obj`.  Then using `which.min` find the row of `DF` having the minimum objective.

```
library(combinat)
sc <- setNames(scoreDf$Score, as.character(scoreDf$Name))
DF <- do.call(rbind, permn(names(sc), function(x) {
  no <- findInterval(29, cumsum(sc[x])) + 1  # only need first no
  data.frame(t(x), no, obj = sum(head(sc[x], no) * 1:no))
}))
ix <- which.min(DF$obj)
cbind(DF[ix, 1:DF[ix, "no"]], obj = DF$obj[ix])
##   X1 X2 obj
## 3  C  A  45
```

Comment: Thanks for your solutions. Excellent

Answer (score 0):

Let me try. The first step would be to develop a mathematical model that would describe the problem. My idea would be to assign students *i* to positions *j* using a binary variable *x(i,j)*. Such a model could look like:

[image]

This is a model with a linear objective and linear constraints, and with binary variables. This is a Mixed Integer Programming (MIP) model and thus requires a MIP solver. R's optim would not fit the bill. Suitable open source solvers could be glpk, lpsolve and COIN CBC (see [here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/views/Optimization.html) for a list).

Note: If the problem is very large there are some possibilities to streamline the model a bit and probably make it more efficient, but for small data sets this formulation should be fine.